# I want to navigate from one scene to another in react native

Tags: react-native, autosuggest

I have a one autocomplete textinput in react native.This autocomplete textinput shows suggestion below the area of textinput and once the user tap on that value ,that value gets set in textinput.Now i want to navigate to next page once the user selects the suggestion value and it set to textinput.Its like when you search search on  google it give you suggestions and when you select any one suggestion,here i want to navigate to next scene once user selects suggestion and set those values to textinput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, you want to push next component on navigation stack with selected props.
You need to provide navigation for your components, take a look at navigator component:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html

When navigation is set, you can navigate and pass props with method:

```
this.props.navigator.push({
    name: 'name_of_your_component',
    passProps: {
        title: 'Components title',
        data: someObject
    }
});
```

If you have a listview providing suggestions, than you can wrap every row to TouchableHighligt. That way you are providing function that fires when row is tapped.

```
renderRow(data) {
    return (
            <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={this.rowTapped.bind(this, data)}>
                <View>
                    <Text>This is a row.</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        );
}
```

Comment: you can catch the text change event in textinput component and then call the function you want. Here is a onChange method:
onChangeText={(text) => this.yourFunction(text)}
Do you have a function that fires on suggestion selection?

Comment: onChangeText function will get called when user types in and not when suggestion gets selected..No I don't have function that fires suggestion selection..

Comment: I have edited my answer. Put suggestions in listView, and render rows in method above

Comment: Solved...!!! renderItem={data => (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>{ this.setState({ query: data });this.print();}}>
        <Text>{data}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

Comment: I'm glad if I helped! Cheers